# Does python have something like C++'s using keyword?

Tags: python, namespaces, using

In C++ you can often drastically improve the readability of your code by careful usage of the "using" keyword, for example:

```
void foo()
{
    std::vector< std::map <int, std::string> > crazyVector;
    std::cout << crazyVector[0].begin()->first;
}
```

becomes

```
void foo()
{
    using namespace std; // limited in scope to foo
    vector< map <int, string> > crazyVector;
    cout << crazyVector[0].begin()->first;
}
```

Does something similar exist for python, or do I have to fully qualify everything?

I'll add the disclaimer that I know that using has its pitfalls and it should be appropriately limited in scope.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Bill said, Python does have the construction

```
from X import *
```

but you can also explicitly specify which names you want imported from the module (namespace):

```
from X import foo, bar, blah
```

This tends to make the code even more readable/easier to understand, since someone seeing an identifier in the source doesn't need to hunt through all imported modules to see where it comes from. Here's a related question: [Namespace Specification In Absence of Ambuguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539578/namespace-specification-in-absence-of-ambuguity)

*EDIT*: in response to Pax's comment, I'll mention that you can also write things like

```
import X.foo
```

but then you'll need to write

```
X.foo.moo()
```

instead of just

```
foo.moo()
```

This is not necessarily a bad thing, of course. I usually use a mixture of the `from X import y` and `import X.y` forms, whatever I feel makes my code clearest. It's certainly a subjective thing to some extent.

Comment: You might want to expand this to include "import X" which then allows you to use X.y things from that module. I sometimes prefer this to reduce polluting the namespace.

Comment: Why "unlike C++"? Can't you use "using std::string;"?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that... I'm not primarily a C++ programmer. Python's import is still a little more powerful though, because you can import individual functions and variables, which I don't think is possible in C++.

Comment: David, it's possible in c++ too. (using a "using declaration"). well. can you explain whether you can use python's "import" within functions too, please?

Comment: Generally yes, in Python "import" is a statement that can be used anywhere, say, a function call could be. The wildcard import can only be used at the module level, though.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, python's dynamism makes this trivial.  If you had a class buried deep in a namespace: foo.bar.baz.blah, you can do:

```
def foo:
    f = foo.bar.baz.blah
    f1 = f()
```

Comment: To me, this is the correct answer in the sense that it is most analogous to the C++ situation. Though typically one would use modified import statements in Python, I sometimes see a need to alias a type like this for the sake of not having to type that long, elaborate type in a particular section of my code.

Answer (score 6):

```
import X
```

or

```
from X import *
```

or

```
from X import a, b, c
```

Where X is the Python module you want to use.

It would be helpful for you to give us a Python code sample that you think needs cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David's answer:

1. One should use round brackets in `from X import (foo, bar, blah)` for a sake of [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. Full syntax allows renaming (rebinding) package names to their new identifiers within the scope of the current module as in `from foo import bar as baz`.

I recommend to look up the manual for the [import keyword](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), the `__import__` built-in and explanation for **sys.modules** as further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in Python is the construct "as" when importing.  For example:

```
from foo import bar as baz
```

This will bring `foo.bar` in as `baz` in the current module which allows the entity to get a different name in the current module, possibly to avoid hiding an existing entity in the current module with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
from foo import bar
```

works even if `bar` is a module in the `foo` package. This lets you limit your namespace pollution without having to name each function/class in `foo.bar` that you might care to use. It also aids readers of your code, because they'll see a call to `bar.baz()` and have a better idea where `baz` came from.